# Pandas - transform column values into new columns with counts

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
        team1  team2   name     counts_team1  counts_team2  match_id
0       266      356   headers             3             1       33
1       266      356   shots               6             5       33
...
```

And I'd like to transform its *n* 'match_id' rows in a single row, like so:

```
        team1  team2  headers_counts_team1  headers_counts_team2 shots_counts_team1 shots_counts_team2 match_id
0       266      356                     3                     1                  6                 5       33
...
```

How do I transform column 'name' values into new columns with counts? I thought about using `pivot_table()`, but since I already have counts aggregated, I think that maybe there's a simpler transformation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `pivot`

```
s = df.pivot(index = ['team1','team2','match_id'],columns='name')
s.columns = s.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
s.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Just use `pivot`:

(df.pivot(['team1', 'team2', 'match_id'], 'name')
   .swaplevel(axis=1)
   .pipe(lambda df: df.set_axis(df.columns.map('_'.join), 
                                axis = 1))
 )

                      headers_counts_team1  shots_counts_team1  headers_counts_team2  shots_counts_team2
team1 team2 match_id
266   356   33                           3                   6                     1                   5
```

A simpler way, without the method chaining,  is to break it down in steps:

```
df = df.pivot(['team1', 'team2', 'match_id'], 'name').swaplevel(axis=1)

df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)

df.reset_index()

   team1  team2  match_id  headers_counts_team1  shots_counts_team1  headers_counts_team2  shots_counts_team2
0    266    356        33                     3                   6                     1                   5
```